# InitialValues aren't populating redux form

Tags: redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

At the moment, I'm having difficulty populating the input fields for a redux form with initial values. Could someone please tell me what's wrong with the following code, or if this is a known issue? Thanks for the help and support.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Field, reduxForm, reset, initialize } from 'redux-form'

const renderField = props => (
  <div>
    <label>{props.placeholder}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...props}/>
      {props.touched && props.error && <span>{props.error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
)


class EditArtist extends Component {

  render() {

    const { initialValues} = this.props;
    console.log(initialValues)

    return (
      <form>
        <Field name="name" component={renderField} type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

const validate = values => {
    const errors = {};
    return errors;
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  initialValues: {
    name: "COOL"
  }
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(reduxForm({
  form: 'edit_artist_form',
  validate,
  enableReinitialize: true
})(EditArtist));
```

Comment: Your code doesn't have anything wrong, so something must be wrong with your reducer setup. Please create a sandbox based on [this template](https://codesandbox.io/s/gJjDoKYWl) for me to help debug your issue.

Comment: @gustavohenke Thanks for the help. Here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/ojvjn6mpmz

Comment: Ah, your `renderField` needs to spread `props.input` instead of `props`. But anyway `initialValues` provided to form on initial render doesn't work since v7.1.2!

Comment: [Here's the related issue](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/3867) I opened about this